# SQL select lapsed customers with 30 day frequency by day

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, window-functions

The goal is to select the count of distinct customer_id's who have not made a purchase in the rolling 30 day period prior to every day in the calendar year 2016. I have created a calendar table in my database to join to.

Here is an example table for reference, let's say you have customers orders normalized as follows:

```
+-------------+------------+----------+
| customer_id | date       | order_id |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| 123         | 01/25/2016 | 1000     |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| 123         | 04/27/2016 | 1025     |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| 444         | 02/02/2016 | 1010     |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| 521         | 01/23/2016 | 998      |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| 521         | 01/24/2016 | 999      |
+-------------+------------+----------+
```

The goal output is effectively a calendar with 1 row for every single day of 2016 with a count on each day of how many customers "lapsed" on that day, meaning their last purchase was 30 days or more prior from that day of the year. The final output will look like this:

```
+------------+--------------+
| date       | lapsed_count |
+------------+--------------+
| 01/01/2016 | 0            |
+------------+--------------+
| 01/02/2016 | 0            |
+------------+--------------+
| ...        | ...          |
+------------+--------------+
| 03/01/2016 | 12           |
+------------+--------------+
| 03/02/2016 | 9            |
+------------+--------------+
| 03/03/2016 | 7            |
+------------+--------------+
```

This data does not exist in 2015, therefore it's not possible for Jan-01-2016 to have a count of lapsed customers because that is the first possible day to ever make a purchase.

So for customer_id #123, they purchased on 01/25/2016 and 04/27/2016. They should have 2 lapse counts because their purchases are more than 30 days apart. One lapse occurring on 2/24/2016 and another lapse on 05/27/2016.
Customer_id#444 only purchased once, so they should have one lapse count for 30 days after 02/02/2016 on 03/02/2016.
Customer_id#521 is tricky, since they purchased with a frequency of 1 day we will not count the first purchase on 03/02/2016, so there is only one lapse starting from their last purchase of 03/03/2016. The count for the lapse will occur on 04/02/2016 (+30 days).

Comment: How does 2016-01-01 have a value of 1?  Weren't all customers lapsed on that day?

Comment: I removed your first paragraph since it does not help at all in understanding the problem. (Besides, your literary style is unimpressive, and you make unwarranted assumptions). Now: How is it that a purchase on 1/25 means a lapse date of 2/25, but 02/02 means lapse on 03/02? What is your definition of "30 days" - it clearly is not based on a simple day count. It also seems customers are "deemed" to have made a purchase on 12/31/2015 (you don't want anyone to be considered "lapsed" for most of January) - that is nonsensical, but it is your problem - the requirement is what you want it to be.

Comment: But that leaves the question... If a customer makes the first purchase in August, they are "lapsed" from January 30 or 31 or February 1 (depending on your definition of "30 days"). That is fine, since you at least "see" this customer in the table. What about, though, customers who don't make ANY purchase at all in 2016 (but who made purchases in the past and also in 2017)? Don't those have to be counted too? And how do **we** know about them - do you also have another table, with all the customers who should be counted?

Comment: thanks for the effort @mathguy, the data doesn't exist before 2016 therefore lapse has no meaning in january. it still makes sense though that a customer could purchase in january, therefore lapsing in feb. The data continues into 2017, so I can see if someone lapses on dec-15-2016.

Comment: @barker - **clarification needed**. Let's say you have one customer who made exactly one purchase, on 3/25/2016. What are the "lapsed dates": 4/25/2016 **only**, or **all** the dates from 4/25/2016 to the present?

Comment: good question, lapse would be defined as the first day where they hit the 30 day limit, so only on 4/25/2016 would it be counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, I didn't read your question properly the first time around.  This query will give you all the lapses you have. It takes each order and uses an analytic function to work out the next order date - if the gap is greater than 30 days then a lapse is recorded

```
WITH
 cust_orders (customer_id , order_date , order_id   )
 AS
  (SELECT 1, TO_DATE('01/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1001 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 1, TO_DATE('29/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1002 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 1, TO_DATE('01/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1003 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, TO_DATE('01/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1004 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, TO_DATE('29/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1005 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, TO_DATE('01/04/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1006 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, TO_DATE('01/06/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1007 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, TO_DATE('01/08/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1008 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('01/09/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1009 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('01/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1010 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('02/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1011 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('03/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1012 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('04/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1013 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('05/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1014 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('06/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1015 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('07/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1016 FROM dual 
  )
SELECT
 customer_id
,order_date
,order_id
,next_order_date
,order_date + 30   lapse_date
FROM
 (SELECT
   customer_id
  ,order_date
  ,order_id
  ,LEAD(order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date) next_order_date
  FROM
   cust_orders
 )
WHERE NVL(next_order_date,sysdate) - order_date > 30
;
```

Now join that to a set of dates and run a COUNT function (enter the year parameter as YYYY) :

```
WITH
 cust_orders (customer_id , order_date , order_id   )
 AS
  (SELECT 1, TO_DATE('01/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1001 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 1, TO_DATE('29/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1002 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 1, TO_DATE('01/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1003 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, TO_DATE('01/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1004 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, TO_DATE('29/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1005 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, TO_DATE('01/04/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1006 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, TO_DATE('01/06/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1007 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, TO_DATE('01/08/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1008 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('01/09/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1009 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('01/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1010 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('02/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1011 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('03/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1012 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('04/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1013 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('05/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1014 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('06/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1015 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('07/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1016 FROM dual 
  )
,calendar (date_value)
 AS
 (SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/'||:P_year,'DD/MM/YYYY') + (rownum -1) 
  FROM all_tables
  WHERE rownum < (TO_DATE('31/12/'||:P_year,'DD/MM/YYYY') - TO_DATE('01/01/'||:P_year,'DD/MM/YYYY')) + 2
 )
SELECT
 calendar.date_value
,COUNT(*)
FROM
 (
  SELECT
   customer_id
  ,order_date
  ,order_id
  ,next_order_date
  ,order_date + 30   lapse_date
  FROM
   (SELECT
     customer_id
    ,order_date
    ,order_id
    ,LEAD(order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date) next_order_date
    FROM
     cust_orders
   )
  WHERE NVL(next_order_date,sysdate) - order_date > 30
 )  lapses
,calendar
WHERE 1=1
AND calendar.date_value = TRUNC(lapses.lapse_date)
GROUP BY
 calendar.date_value
;
```

Or if you really want every date printed out then use this :

```
WITH
 cust_orders (customer_id , order_date , order_id   )
 AS
  (SELECT 1, TO_DATE('01/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1001 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 1, TO_DATE('29/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1002 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 1, TO_DATE('01/03/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1003 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, TO_DATE('01/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1004 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, TO_DATE('29/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1005 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, TO_DATE('01/04/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1006 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, TO_DATE('01/06/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1007 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, TO_DATE('01/08/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1008 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('01/09/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1009 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('01/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1010 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('02/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1011 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('03/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1012 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('04/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1013 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('05/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1014 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('06/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1015 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, TO_DATE('07/12/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1016 FROM dual 
  )
,lapses
 AS
  (SELECT
    customer_id
   ,order_date
   ,order_id
   ,next_order_date
   ,order_date + 30   lapse_date
   FROM
    (SELECT
      customer_id
     ,order_date
     ,order_id
     ,LEAD(order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date) next_order_date
     FROM
      cust_orders
    )
   WHERE NVL(next_order_date,sysdate) - order_date > 30
  )  
,calendar (date_value)
 AS
 (SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/'||:P_year,'DD/MM/YYYY') + (rownum -1) 
  FROM all_tables
  WHERE rownum < (TO_DATE('31/12/'||:P_year,'DD/MM/YYYY') - TO_DATE('01/01/'||:P_year,'DD/MM/YYYY')) + 2
 )
SELECT
 calendar.date_value
,(SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM lapses
  WHERE calendar.date_value = lapses.lapse_date
 )
FROM
 calendar
WHERE 1=1
ORDER BY
 calendar.date_value
;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a table of dates, here is one expensive method:

```
select date,
       sum(case when prev_date < date - 30 then 1 else 0 end) as lapsed
from (select c.date, o.customer_id, max(o.date) as prev_date
      from calendar c cross join
           (select distinct customer_id from orders) c left join
           orders o
           on o.date <= c.date and o.customer_id = c.customer_id
      group by c.date, o.customer_id
     ) oc
group by date;
```

For each date/customer pair, it determines the latest purchase the customer made before the date.  It then uses this information to count the lapsed.

To be honest, this will probably work well on a handful of dates, but not for a full year's worth.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, looks complicated. I'm trying to read through your code and I am unsure if you are catching the edge case where customers place multiple orders on the same day. It does appear you account for ignoring the purchases with frequency under 30 days which is good. I'll continue playing with this before finalizing the answer, thanks!

Comment: @barker . . . Multiple orders on the same day wouldn't affect this query.  It is looking for periods of 30 days with *no* order.  No order is the same whether there is one order per day or more.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 123 customer_id, to_date('24/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_date, 12345 order_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 123 customer_id, to_date('24/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_date, 12346 order_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 123 customer_id, to_date('25/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_date, 12347 order_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 123 customer_id, to_date('24/02/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_date, 12347 order_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 123 customer_id, to_date('16/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_date, 12348 order_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 123 customer_id, to_date('18/04/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_date, 12349 order_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 456 customer_id, to_date('20/02/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_date, 12350 order_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 456 customer_id, to_date('01/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_date, 12351 order_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 456 customer_id, to_date('03/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_date, 12352 order_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 456 customer_id, to_date('18/04/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_date, 12353 order_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 456 customer_id, to_date('20/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_date, 12354 order_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 456 customer_id, to_date('23/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_date, 12355 order_id FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 456 customer_id, to_date('19/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_date, 12356 order_id FROM dual),
-- end of mimicking your_table with data in it
    lapsed_info AS (SELECT customer_id,
                           order_date,
                           CASE WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - order_date <= 30 THEN NULL
                                WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 30 FOLLOWING) = 0 THEN order_date+30
                                ELSE NULL
                           END lapsed_date
                    FROM   your_table),
          dates AS (SELECT to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + LEVEL -1 dt
                    FROM   dual
                    CONNECT BY to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + LEVEL -1 <= TRUNC(SYSDATE))
SELECT dates.dt,
       COUNT(li.lapsed_date) lapsed_count
FROM   dates
       LEFT OUTER JOIN lapsed_info li ON dates.dt = li.lapsed_date
GROUP BY dates.dt
ORDER BY dates.dt;
```

Results:

```
DT         LAPSED_COUNT
---------- ------------
01/01/2016            0
<snip>
23/01/2016            0
24/01/2016            0
25/01/2016            0
26/01/2016            0
<snip>
19/02/2016            0
20/02/2016            0
21/02/2016            0
22/02/2016            0
23/02/2016            0
24/02/2016            1
25/02/2016            0
<snip>
29/02/2016            0
01/03/2016            0
02/03/2016            0
03/03/2016            0
04/03/2016            0
<snip>
15/03/2016            0
16/03/2016            0
17/03/2016            0
<snip>
20/03/2016            0
21/03/2016            0
22/03/2016            0
<snip>
30/03/2016            0
31/03/2016            0
01/04/2016            0
02/04/2016            1
03/04/2016            0
<snip>
14/04/2016            0
15/04/2016            1
16/04/2016            0
17/04/2016            0
18/04/2016            0
19/04/2016            0
<snip>
17/05/2016            0
18/05/2016            2
19/05/2016            0
20/05/2016            0
21/05/2016            0
<snip>
18/06/2016            0
19/06/2016            1
20/06/2016            0
21/06/2016            0
22/06/2016            0
23/06/2016            0
24/06/2016            0
<snip>
22/07/2016            0
23/07/2016            1
24/07/2016            0
<snip>
18/01/2017            0
19/01/2017            0
20/01/2017            0
<snip>
08/02/2017            0
```

This takes your data, and uses an the analytic count function to work out the number of rows that have a value within 30 days of (but excluding) the current row's date.

Then we apply a case expression to determine that if the row has a date within 30 days of today's date, we'll count those as not lapsed. If a count of 0 was returned, then the row is considered lapsed and we'll output the lapsed date as the order_date plus 30 days. Any other count result means the row has not lapsed.

The above is all worked out in the `lapsed_info` subquery.

Then all we need to do is list the dates (see the `dates` subquery) and outer join the lapsed_info subquery to it based on the lapsed_date and then do a count of the lapsed dates for each day.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, but: I copied and pasted your query exactly as is and I ran it - and it returns 405 rows. That can't be right, there should be 366 rows.  :-)

Comment: I went for the start of 2016 to today; it's simple enough to change the sysdate referenced in the query to the last day in 2016, if that's what the OP wants.

Comment: More likely I missed that bit of the question when I read it! *{;-)

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, if there is only one customer who made only one purchase on 3/15/2016, you are counting a single "lapse date" on 4/15/2016. That is not the requirement; ALL days starting from 4/15/2016 and extended to the present are "lapsed status" days for that customer.

Comment: The requirement is unclear. The OP seems to contradict theirself - for the customer 123, they say there are two lapse counts, which is what I took to mean they were after the days at which the customer lapsed. Hey ho, I guess I need to wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: Two more things: (1) (I just realized this for my solution too) Since we do a left join of the calendar to the "lapsed" view, it doesn't hurt if "lapsed" has dates past SYSDATE. They will be ignored anyway. (Although for the join it may be more efficient not to have them... so perhaps it's OK to exclude them explicitly). (2) in the CONNECT BY condition, it is always more efficient to express it as `level <= <expression>`. This way the RHS is the same for all rows, and computed only once. Otherwise there's different arithmetic for each row.

Comment: the logic is not a contradiction. The lapse count should only happen when the 30 day limit is hit, not every day thereafter. Customer 123 is not a contradiction because their purchases exist outside of the 30 day window, so they have 2 distinct lapses.

Comment: @barker if you go with restricting the dates in the lapsed_info subquery, - e.g. say you're looking for lapsed dates in the year 2017 - then you'd need to include the 30 days before the start of 2017 in order to get the information for customers who'd lapse within the first 30 days of 2017.